# Powershell select-object skip multiple lines?

Tags: powershell

Can i skip multiple lines with the -skip option?

```
gc d:\testfile.txt | select -skip 3
```

works but what to do if i want to delet line 3-7 ??

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can also use the readcount property to exclude lines:

```
get-content d:\testfile.txt | where {$_.readcount -lt 3 -or $_.readcount -gt 7}
```

Answer (score 8):

If I need to select only some lines, I would directly index into the array:

```
$x = gc c:\test.txt
$x[(0..2) + (8..($x.Length-1))]
```

It is also possible to create a function `Skip-Objects`

```
function Skip-Object {
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,ValueFromPipeline=$true)][PsObject]$InputObject,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][int]$From,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][int]$To
    )

    begin {
        $i = -1
    }
    process {
        $i++
        if ($i -lt $from -or $i -gt $to)  {
            $InputObject
        }
    }
}

1..6 | skip-object -from 1 -to 2   #returns 1,4,5,6
'a','b','c','d','e' | skip-object -from 1 -to 2 #returns a, d, e
```

Answer (score 5):

The [PowerShell Community Extensions](http://pscx.codeplex.com) comes with a Skip-Object cmdlet:

```
PS> 0..10 | Skip-Object -Index (3..7)
0
1
2
8
9
10
```

Note that the Index parameter is 0-based.

Comment: Seems now to work with `| Select-Object -Index (...)` as well, without using any extensions.

Comment: Indeed. PowerShell continues to improve and has gotten a lot of new features over the past 12 years.

Answer (score 3):

Similarly, without extensions (note that `-skip` needs the number of items to skip, and not an index)

```
$content = get-content d:\testfile.txt
($content | select -first 3), ($content | select -skip 8)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$list = @(1..9)
@(($list | Select-Object -First 2), ($list | Select-Object -Skip 7))

$list = @(1..19)
@(($list | Select-Object -First 2), ($list | Select-Object -Skip 7 -First 2))
```

`-First = Take()`